# my hp 2000 wont recognize usb

Tags: usb-drive

My laptop has no boot OS whatsoever and I wanted to install Ubuntu using a USB because my disk drive is broken. But when I tried to install it using a USB, the USB wont recognize in the boot options. I know there is a lot of people with this problem because before I ask for help any where I research first but every one who had SIMILAR problems had answers that I could not use. so I ask for my self.

I have tried to do the following:

1) I have tried booting from "usb diskette on key/usb hard disk" in the bios boot options.

2) I have tried to press <kbd>F9</kbd> to boot from USB there but there was nothing to select.

3) I tried to boot from Ethernet but due to me not knowing what I was doing and me being in the library that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Increase your USB's boot priority on the BIOS options. What is happening is that as things stands, your OS has a higher boot priority that a USB device. To increase the USB's boot priority do the following:

- Switch on your computer and depending the manufacturer of your BIOS, press either  <kbd>ESC</kbd>, <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F8</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd> the moment your PC switches on(Note that one of this keys should work, as to which one exactly, this differ from PC to PC, depending on the BIOS manufacturer hence I suggested all the above keys). The BIOS setup utility page should appear, mine looks like this:

[image: Bios main]

- Go to the "Boot" tab.

[image: Increase USB boot priority]

- Using the arrows keys, move the [USB] up the boot priority(in my case it is on position 4). I suggest you move it all the way up to number one for now(you can always come back and move it down the priority list once the installation is done).
- Go to the "Exit" tab and choose to save changes and exit:
  [image: save changes and exit]
- Shutdown your PC and insert the USB you want to install Ubuntu from(if you moved the USB all the way to number one on the priority list, sit back and relax, your PC should boot from the USB automatically, no need to press any keys)
- Continue with the Ubuntu installation process.